# mod_rewrite for sub directory

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have a domain and a sub folder, called "sub"..inside "sub" is index.php which has this:

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
switch ($page)
{
    case "main":
        echo "main";
        break;
    case "task_orders":
        echo "task_orders";
        break;
    case "team_members":
        echo "team_members";
        break;
    case "team_experience":
        echo "team_experience";
        break;
    case "quality_assurance":
        echo "quality_assurance";
        break;
    case "geographical_support":
        echo "geographical_support";
        break;
    case "contact":
        echo "contact";
        break;
    default:
        echo "main";
}
```

my htaccess in "sub" is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^sub/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

when I click a link which looks like:

```
<li><a href="/sub/main" title="Main" class="current">Main</a></li>
<li><a href="/sub/task_orders" title="Task Orders">Task Orders</a></li> 
<li><a href="/sub/team_members" title="Team Members">Team Members</a></li> 
<li><a href="/sub/team_experience" title="Team Experience">Team Experience</a></li> 
<li><a href="/sub/quality_assurance" title="Quality Assurance Program">Quality Assurance</a></li> 
<li><a href="/sub/geographical_support" title="Geographical Support">Geographical Support</a></li> 
<li><a href="/sub/contact" title="Points of Contact">Points of Contact</a></li>
```

I get a page not found rather than echoing out what page I am on, any ideas?

I also tried:

```
RewriteRule ^/sub/([^/\.]+)/?$ /sub/index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

and same result

Comment: Look at the access log to see what's being requested. Step #1 in debugging rewrite rules is LOOK AT THE LOGS.

Comment: unfortunately, they contain nothing pertaining to the web site I am working on. I am on a dedicated server so I do have access to the logs and they havent been updated for about an hour and I have been trying quite a bit of rewrite combos

Comment: There should be a line for every hit you've performed. If the logs you're looking at haven't been updated, then those aren't the "live" logs.

Comment: that is what I thought too..I am at the root of my server in the /logs folder..along side that folder is /etc, /users, /stats and a few others

Comment: Check for `CustomLog` and the like in the Apache configuration. That'll tell you exactly where they are. Usually that's in `/var/log/httpd` or `/var/log/apache`, or similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there. You don't want to specify the leading `/` when writing the `RewriteRule`.

**In the document root:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^sub/([^/\.]+)/?$ /sub/index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

**From the /sub folder:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: still getting a 404 `RewriteRule ^sub/([^/\.]+)/?$ /sub/index.php?page=$1 [L]` do you think it has something to do with an htaccess being in root?

Comment: @Ronnie - It should be in root. I've tested the line above on my testing server by creating the `.htaccess` in the root, a folder called `sub` and an `index.php` located inside the `sub` folder. Are you sure that the `.htaccess` file is being read by your server?

Comment: ok I had the htaccess in the sub directory. I added it to the root htaccess and it is now working. So is it safe to assume always use htaccess at root level?

Comment: @Ronnie - Not necessarily. You could have placed it in the folder too but the content would have been a little different.

Comment: yeah I see that from the Floern's post. Both of these methods worked

Answer (score 3):

If your .htaccess is in a subdirectory, you don't have to write the full path in a RewriteRule.

So use this in your .htaccess in sub-directory:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

or in root's .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^sub/([^/\.]+)/?$ sub/index.php?page=$1 [L]
```