# How Remove a folder form url using .htacces

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I develop a new site for a client and I don't want to move to the root folder of the server.
Besides that, the hosting service do not alow me to change the physical path.
So I decide to use .htaccess to handle this.
My .htaccess file is like this:

```
AddHandler php56-script .php
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/balletpaulacastro/
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
```

So when the user try to access www.balletpaulacastro.com.br they will be redirected to www.balletpaulacastro.com.br/bpc where the new site is located.

What i want is to rewrite the url to not show de /bpc/ folder.

I try many examples, but i'm not a coder, so if you guys can write down the entire code with my actual url and folders, that will be so nice.

Thanks in advance
Raul

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mod\_rewrite for sub directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668423/mod-rewrite-for-sub-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^((?!bpc).*)$ /bpc/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

This will rewrite

- example.com

to

- example.com/bpc

Comment: Hi there.What i want is just the opposite, i need the URL www.balletpaulacastro.com.br/bpc to be rewritten to www.balletpaulacastro.com

Comment: Could you be spacific ?

Comment: Your orignal post is not about redirecting /folder to /root, it's about "Rewriting from /root to /folder".